# Why isnt this Jquery If and Or Statement working?

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I have this if statement that works on two different pages, however these two pages both have a field with a different name, so I have to use the OR in my If statement, But its not working.  Here is my code...

```
if ($("#searchValue").val().length > 100 || $("#txtSearch").val().length > 100) {
}
```

Why I debug, it says "Uncaught type error: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined".  
Is this because one of the property ID's doesn't exist on the page or what?  how do I get around this?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`val` returns `undefined` when the jQuery collection is empty.

You can do this :

```
    var s1 = $("#searchValue").val();
    var s2 = $("#txtSearch").val();
    if ((s1 && s1.length>100) || (s2 && s2.length>100)) {
```

Another solution if you're sure to have exactly one of the two fields:

```
    if ($("#searchValue, #txtSearch").val().length>100) {
```

Comment: Oh, so how can I get around that or would I need another if statement checking if they are empty?

Answer (score 1):

change it to

```
if (($("#searchValue").val()!=null && $("#searchValue").val().length > 100) || ($("#txtSearch").val()!=null && $("#txtSearch").val().length > 100)) {
}
```

instead of

```
if ($("#searchValue").val().length > 100 || $("#txtSearch").val().length > 100) {
}
```